# Finding index of the first non-zero element starting from the bottom of a column

Tags: r, dataframe

In a data frame dt of dimension 76x108, I want to reduce the sum of values in each columns 13 to 108 by an amount stored in an array c, by minimising the non-zero elements in the column, starting from the last row.

For example, if dt[76,13] > 0, the following happens:

`dt[76,13] <- max((dt[76,13]-c),0)`

If after this operation dt[76,13] == 0, the residual of c - dt[76,13] should get subtracted from the next non-zero element in column 13. This goes on until the sum of all rows in column 13 is reduced by an amount equivalent to c.

This needs to be done for the 96 columns in dt[,13:108].

Edited: Added an example with a smaller data frame below.

```
dt <- data.frame(Plant = sample(LETTERS,10,replace=T),
                 Type = rep("Base",10),
                 Ownership = rep("Pub",10))

caps = matrix(round(runif(10*5,0,500),0),nrow=10,ncol=5)

dt <- as.data.frame(cbind(dt,caps))  #this what the data frame looks like

for(i in 1:5){
  colnames(dt)[i+3] <- (paste0("TB",i))
}

dt

  Plant Type Ownership TB1 TB2 TB3 TB4 TB5
1      T Base       Pub 454  32 162 271 478
2      S Base       Pub 275  75 385 491  60
3      Y Base       Pub 314  44 252 221 363
4      T Base       Pub 170 122 490 332 123
5      J Base       Pub 241 178 173 472 468
6      B Base       Pub 243 316 152 411 434
7      T Base       Pub 127 167 356 451 400
8      U Base       Pub  20 102  54 182  57
9      O Base       Pub 368 333 236 103  27
10     J Base       Pub 343 189   0 494 184

c <- c(500,200,217,50,300)

#required output

  Plant Type Ownership TB1 TB2 TB3 TB4 TB5
1      T Base       Pub 454  32 162 271 478
2      S Base       Pub 275  75 385 491  60
3      Y Base       Pub 314  44 252 221 363
4      T Base       Pub 170 122 490 332 123
5      J Base       Pub 241 178 173 472 468
6      B Base       Pub 243 316 152 411 434
7      T Base       Pub 127 167 356 451 368
8      U Base       Pub  20 102  54 182   0
9      O Base       Pub 211 322  19 103   0
10     J Base       Pub   0   0   0 444   0 

#dt[10,4] is now max((343-500),0), while dt[9,4] is 368-(500-343). 
#dt[10,5] is now max((189-200),0), while dt[9,4] is 333-(200-189).
#and so on.
```

What I've tried so far looks something like this:

```
for(i in 4:8){
  j <- nrow(dt)                             #start from the last row
    if(dt[j,i]>0){
      res1 <- c[i] - dt[j,i]                #residual value of the difference
      dt[j,i] <- max((dt[j,i] - c[i]),0)  
      while(res1>0){            #the process should continue until an amount equivalent to c[i] is not subtracted from dt[j,i] 
        j <- j-1
        p <- dt[j,i]
        dt[j,i] <- max((dt[j,i] - res1),0)
        res1 <- res1 - p
      }
    }
    else if(dt[j,i]==0){    #if the last element of the column is already 0, process should start w/ the first non-zero element
      j <- j-1  
      res1 <- c[i] - dt[j,i]
      dt[j,i] <- max((dt[j,i] - c[i]),0) 
      while(res1>0){
        j <- j-1
        p <- dt[j,i]
        dt[j,i] <- max((dt[j,i] - res1),0)
        res1 <- res1 - p
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: `I want to subtract a constant c from it, such that, df[76,13] <- max((df[76,13]-c),0)` is not clear to me.  As Ronak has stated, please create a small reproducible example alongwith a desired output, so that you can be understood

Comment: @RonakShah example added. Thanks.

Comment: @RonakShah edited the example. Thanks.

Comment: @dhruvak_a, solved it without loops i.e. following `dplyr` strategy only.  You may replace str_replace with gsub/sub if you don't want to use `stringr`

Comment: @AnilGoyal thanks, the code ran fine the first couple of times. But now its converting the first few rows of the dataset into NA. Any idea why that might be? Doesn't seem to be an issue with the class.

Comment: Have you checked length of `cc` vector that it is equal to number of columns to be mutated?  See if it is unable to return a value, NA will introduced unexpectedly

Comment: Checked. Lengths are exactly the same. Issue is still there. With smaller, example data frame its working fine. But with the actual, larger data frame, its coercing the first 35 out of 76 rows into NAs.

Comment: In your sample, TB columns ended in perfect sequence.  So I used their suffixes directly as indices to extract values from `cc`.  Check this behaviour in your actual data.  If so, the code will need modification

Comment: I just checked with your earlier shared example with TB96 columns, It is running perfectly there

Comment: I'm using read.csv to import the data. Seems like its something to do with how the data is being read.

Comment: Yes, that may be possible.  Check variable types before proceeding further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do your purpose. (I renamed your vector `c` with `cc` so that it may not interact with function `c`)

```r
df <- read.table(text = ' Plant Type Ownership TB1 TB2 TB3 TB4 TB5
1      T Base       Pub 454  32 162 271 478
2      S Base       Pub 275  75 385 491  60
3      Y Base       Pub 314  44 252 221 363
4      T Base       Pub 170 122 490 332 123
5      J Base       Pub 241 178 173 472 468
6      B Base       Pub 243 316 152 411 434
7      T Base       Pub 127 167 356 451 400
8      U Base       Pub  20 102  54 182  57
9      O Base       Pub 368 333 236 103  27
10     J Base       Pub 343 189   0 494 184', header =T)


cc <- c(500,200,217,50,300)
library(tidyverse)

df %>% arrange(rev(row_number())) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('TB'), ~ . - c(first(pmin(cc[as.integer(str_remove(cur_column(), 'TB'))], 
                                                 cumsum(pmin(., cc[as.integer(str_remove(cur_column(), 'TB'))])))),
                                      diff(pmin(cc[as.integer(str_remove(cur_column(), 'TB'))],
                                                cumsum(pmin(., cc[as.integer(str_remove(cur_column(), 'TB'))])))))
                )) %>%
  arrange(rev(row_number()))
#>    Plant Type Ownership TB1 TB2 TB3 TB4 TB5
#> 1      T Base       Pub 454  32 162 271 478
#> 2      S Base       Pub 275  75 385 491  60
#> 3      Y Base       Pub 314  44 252 221 363
#> 4      T Base       Pub 170 122 490 332 123
#> 5      J Base       Pub 241 178 173 472 468
#> 6      B Base       Pub 243 316 152 411 434
#> 7      T Base       Pub 127 167 356 451 368
#> 8      U Base       Pub  20 102  54 182   0
#> 9      O Base       Pub 211 322  19 103   0
#> 10     J Base       Pub   0   0   0 444   0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>